# Drupal How to see document attached to Node for anonymous users

Tags: drupal

I am finishing up a Drupal site and I have attached a word document on one of my page nodes. I want anonymous people to be able to download it, but they don't even see the document. I do as a logged in user.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give anonymous users permission to view uploaded files.
I'm guessing that you used the upload module. 
The permissions page is at /admin/user/permissions and under the group "upload module" you are looking for "view uploaded files".

-Ed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to enable this one particular file to anonymous users, you can do it without touching permissions, which would affect your whole site.

The simplest way, assuming you have configured downloads as "public" instead of "private" is to just add a link to the document in your page node, like <a href="/files/myfile.doc">Download myfile.doc</a>